# Dropbox python api list a list of files

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dropbox-api

In my code, I need to get a list of the files with the dropbox api. My app has a single folder, and it does not have any folders inside it. What I want is `["file1.py", "file2.sh", "file3.something", "file4"]`. How can I make a list of these files?

Note: I am using Dropbox API v2.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`metadata` api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata).

`client` below is `dropbox.client.DropboxClient` object. assuming it's created using [authorization](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/python#authenticating) token:

```
metadata = client.metadata('/foldername')
files = [content['path'].split('/')[-1] for content in metadata['contents']]
```

---

[Complete code I tested](http://pastebin.com/VGdGQz6z) (app_key, app_secret, folder_name should be filled)

Answer (score 1):

Falsetru's answer is correct, but you may want to add the `content['is_dir']` filter, if you want just files or just folders, like this:

```
metadata = client.metadata('/foldername')
files = [content['path'].split('/')[-1] for content in metadata['contents'] if content['is_dir'] == False]
```

Change ['is_dir'] to True for folder, leave out for both.
Sorry for the double answer, don't have rep to comment.

Comment: You can always comment on your questions/answers and on answers to your questions. To comment elsewhere requires 50 reputation - it is a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).